# Why is my wall thicker in one area and what can I do about it?

Tags: drywall, walls

[image: strange wall with openings]I own a 1960-1970's home that was flipped before I purchased it. The flippers did some crazy things, one of which is this wall. It is thicker in one area and has 3 "decorative" rectangular cut-outs within the thicker area. The thicker portion runs to the floor, is a little over 6 feet tall, and maybe the same in width. It protrudes out on both sides of the wall but one side sticks out a little further.[image: why is my wall like this and how can I fix it?]
I've been puzzling over WHY this was done this way on purpose if it was on purpose at all. I would like to cover this up and make the entire wall flush. What would be the simplest course of action?

Comment: Many "flippers" have limited knowledge of a homes construction. Because of that and the desire to do as little as possible and only hit the cosmetic issues combined with spending the least amount of money, there are untold reasons why something may have been done.   Your easiest "fix is to cover the "thinner areas with another layer of drywall, tape, mud and paint.   If you are feeling adventurous you could cut into the thick part to see what is there, but that may reveal a nightmare.

Comment: You can use a small drill bit to poke into the wall somewhat noninvasively. Spackle and paint to repair. Then at least you could discover if these are layers of drywall stacked behind the popout or if the framed wall is thicker in this area. Is there anything interesting below this wall in the basement? Coming out of this wall into the attic? Is that wall load bearing?

Comment: What is the thickness of the thick part?  And is it plastered or concrete blocks (cinder blocks I think you call them in US)?  Maybe the original wall was poured and the added one is made from standard blocks.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that the house didn't originally have those openings, and the thickness is for a header to support the structure above those openings.  Likely your other wall sections are based on 2x4 construction, and it looks like this was likely using 2x6.  As said by @RMDman, the easiest is to bring out the narrow sections with drywall, and texture/paint to match.

Comment: My only theory along your thinking was that somebody used an inadequately sized header, got busted, and settled for an additional ply to meet code. I just can't rationalize a header. Is the theory that the openings in that wall are so desirable that the header was warranted?